# Polymer Fire-base Login Returning User as 'null'

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebasesimplelogin

so I'm trying to build a nice multi-tabbed login form using polymer and the `<firebase-login>` element. It looks something like this: https://ele.io/caseybaggz/paper-form

One one tab, I have some social login buttons (google, twitter, fb), on the other, email/password login/register. I'm also using `<app-router>` on my `index.html` to route all my views(elements), and the `<pvc-globals>` to hold global objects. So, when user's are logged in, they are routed to a new element. Here is the login code:

```
   login: function() {
      if (debug) {
        console.log('Logging in');
        console.log('loginProvider: ' + this.$.login.provider);
        console.log('loginUser: ' + this.$.login.user);
        console.log('global.currentUser: ' + this.globals.currentUser);
      }

      var params;

      try {
        params = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#params").value);
      } catch (e) {
        params = null;
      }

      if (this.provider == 'password') {
        params = this.params || {};
        params.email = this.email;
        params.password = this.userPassword;
      }

      this.globals.currentUser = this.user;
      this.$.login.login(params);

      // If login successful
      window.location.href = "#/home";
    },
```

It's basically the same thing that the firebase demo gives.
So, for some reason, I can log people in successfully, but when I console the firebase `user` object, it returns `null`. Also, the login function is re-routing people faster than firebase is logging user's in with the social buttons.

**My main question:** Why is firebase saying the user object is null after a successful login? The second part of that would be how to re-route users *AFTER* the login takes it's course?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks related: https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/issues/42

Comment: @Kato I think it is a little, but I've updated the code base and it's still not fixed?

Comment: Post your firebase-login element.

Comment: @JWL_   `<!-- firebase -->
    <firebase-login id="login" user="{{user}}" statusKnown="{{statusKnown}}" 
      location="https:/<YOUR URL>" provider="{{provider}}" 
      on-error="{{error}}" on-user-created="{{userSuccess}}" on-password-changed="{{userSuccess}}" 
      on-password-reset="{{userSuccess}}" on-user-removed="{{userSuccess}}">
    </firebase-login>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use the "real" api instead of the firebase-login wrapper.
In your case I'm guessing
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthpopup.html
And do the redirect in the callback from the auth method. Same with settings the globals value.

OR

You can define a on-login function on the firebase-login and do the redirect and setting globals value in that function.